# What is the meaning of a question mark [?] for number of data frame dplyr groups in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

When you output a `dplyr`-grouped data frame in R, it shows the number of groups, like so:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, vs)

# Groups:   cyl, vs [5]
```

I've noticed that if you group and summarize, it shows the number of groups as a question mark, like so:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, vs) %>% summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

# Groups:   cyl [?]
```

What is the meaning of the question mark?

Comment: After the summarise step, one of the grouping variable is dropped i.e. the last one 'vs'.  If you check the output with `mutate`, there is no such thing as both the groups are still there

Comment: Shouldn't there still be 3 groups for `cyl`, though?

Comment: It is there, but it gives the [] for the combination of groups.  As one of them is missing, it gives `?`

Comment: Also, you can check the output, it is a 5 x 3 dimension.  So, nothing is lost.  I am not sure whether this is by design or not.

Comment: Has to be that it wants to show you that a grouping variable was just dropped, as it goes back to `[3]` if the next command doesn't affect the grouping. Like this `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>% 
  summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  mutate(mean_mpg = as.character(mean_mpg))`. Maybe in the background after a `summarize` the number of groups will be obtained again after the next command is executed.